# Which CFD software is used in Boeing and Airbus?

Tags: aerodynamics, cfd

Which Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD) software is used in Boeing and Airbus, and in the aircraft industry generally?

Comment: Please tell those of us not so knowledgeable what CFD stands for.

Comment: All of them… In such big companies, you will find that each group chooses its favorite tool, sometimes few tools

Comment: @hdrz,open foam?

Comment: @IQ240 Probably openFOAM as well. With the right pre- and post- processors you can use any solver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Airbus [develops its own](https://www.airbus.com/newsroom/news/en/2018/01/a-partnership-for-next-generation-computational-fluid-dynamics.html) CFD software, developed in cooperation with national aerodynamics laboratories like ONERA and DLR.

Boeing does [something similar](http://calmarresearch.com/NF/STG/AGPS/media/aiaa-2003-3439.pdf):

> Boeing Commercial Airplanes has leveraged academia- and NASA-developed CFD technology, some developed under contract by Boeing Commercial Airplanes, into engineering tools used in new airplane development.

Comment: ,So they dont use comercial softwears..i didnt know that

Comment: Boeing and Airbus started using CFD software before commercial solutions existed, so they basically had to develop their own. Something similar happened with CAD: Dassault developed [CATIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CATIA), and ended up making it available commercially.